# What kind of science jobs are there at the European level?

Tags: job-search, job, community

I'm thinking about opportunities for PhDs beyond the traditional academic route, for example in policy. I'm curious then, to hear about what kind of work there is at the level of the European Commission. Googling the keywords just brings me an endless stream of commission webpages, plenty of jobs in the massive associated bureaucracy, but little idea of what kind of opportunities there may be, or what kinds of profiles are optimal.

Any input you guys may have would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.